# how to print output in hexadecimal format

Tags: solver, smt

this Boolector program printing output in binary format. But I need in hexadecimal format.
so how to print hexdecimal format in boolector.

```
(set-logic QF_BV)
(set-info :smt-lib-version 2.0)

(declare-const val1  (_ BitVec 16))
(declare-const val2  (_ BitVec 16))

(declare-const gen_mul  (_ BitVec 16))
(declare-const eval1  (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const eval2  (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const org_mul  (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const rem17 (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-const res (_ BitVec 16))

(assert (= gen_mul (bvmul val1 val2)))
(assert (= eval1 (concat #x0000 val1)))
(assert (= eval2 (concat #x0000 val2)))
(assert (= org_mul (bvmul eval1 eval2)))
(assert (= rem17 (bvurem org_mul #x00010001)))
(assert (= res ((_ extract 15 0) rem17)))
(assert (= val1 #xb621))
(assert (= val2 #xd620))
(check-sat)

(get-value (val1))
(get-value (val2))
(get-value (org_mul))
(get-value (gen_mul))
(get-value (eval1))
(get-value (eval2))
(get-value (org_mul))
(get-value (rem17))
(get-value (res))
(exit)
```

Run:
./boolector ex.smt2

Comment: I doubt that Boolector offers this functionality - you'll probably have to convert the output yourself

Answer (score 0):

Boolector (at least version 2.2.0) has the `-x, --hex` options to force hexadecimal output. It's possible that it may ignore those options if a bit-vector's size is not a multiple of 4.